# Add default value while groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with Pandas dataframe and my data has Date, Events and Count as columns.

```
Date        Events     Count
1/1/2021    Event1      2
1/1/2021    Event2      1
2/1/2021    Event1      2
1/2/2021    Event1      1
2/1/2021    Event2      1
3/2/2021    Event3      2
3/2/2021    Event3      2
```

I want to groupby of events if it repeats in the same month and give default value as 1 in count column.

```
Date        Events  Count
1/1/2021    Event1    1
1/1/2021    Event2    1
1/2/2021    Event1    1
3/2/2021    Event3    1
```

Comment: Is ouput correct? because seems `2/1/2021    Event1` is lost.

Comment: Yes it is correct, I want to remove events if it is repeating in the same month.

Comment: hmmm,  `3/2/2021` is march or february?

Comment: February.. So the format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with set `1` to `Count` column:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df['months'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('m')


df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['months','Events']).assign(Count=1)
print (df1)
        Date  Events  Count   months
0 2021-01-01  Event1      1  2021-01
1 2021-01-01  Event2      1  2021-01
3 2021-02-01  Event1      1  2021-02
5 2021-02-03  Event3      1  2021-02

df1 = df1.drop('months', axis=1)
print (df1)
        Date  Events  Count
0 2021-01-01  Event1      1
1 2021-01-01  Event2      1
3 2021-02-01  Event1      1
5 2021-02-03  Event3      1
```

Comment: I also want data to be groupby by month. I have edited question. Thanks

Comment: @Primecoder - why is change `3/2/2021` to `3/1/2021` in expected ouput? Edited solution working like need?

Comment: - I want monthly event groupby and give them count as 1.

Comment: @Primecoder - what means `monthly event` ? Need one row per month?  Or something different?

Comment: I have edited question, if event repeat in same month then it should groupby to single event.

Comment: answer was edited.

Comment: We don't want to drop multiple events on the same date.  But want to drop if same event is repeating in a month only want to keep single entry of it @jezrael

Comment: @Primecoder - added to answer, because ouput is different if need it.

Comment: Still I am getting repeated events in the month.

Comment: @Primecoder - Can you test now?